# How is variable expanded when containing single quote

Tags: bash, shell

I hit the problem when I'm trying to specify some JVM opts. Suppose I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='echo error' -Xmx10m"

java -cp test.jar $OPTS java.Test
```

I get this error when running the script:

> Error: Could not find or load main class error'

Verified everything works fine if I use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp test.jar -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='echo error' -Xmx10m java.Test
```

Is there any way to make the first script work?

Comment: [Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can quote the `OPTS` variable like,

```
java -cp test.jar "$OPTS" java.Test
```

Comment: I tried that but them I got the following error
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="'echo error' -Xmx10m"
#   Executing "'echo error' -Xmx10m"...
sh: echo error: command not found

Comment: @RuiLi Try `/bin/echo`... But really, what value is there in echoing "error" when the JVM is out of memory?

Comment: It still won't work - "/bin/echo error" will be treated as the command. Of course we can do something more useful than printing an error, e.g. 'kill -3 %p'. But then we just hit the same issue.